# I have a big list of keywords with so many garbage and little useful ones, which algorithm should I use to classify them?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, stanford-nlp, text-mining

I have gathered 1.2 million keywords for my new web site project.

But the problem is big portion of the keywords are irrelevant for my project and just a %3 of the keywords are relevant and useful.

I was thinking using classification algorithms to classify useful ones and trash ones.

For useful and relevant keywords there are 30 pre-fixed categories that I've determined.

I've tried Stanford classifier but since big portion of the keywords are trash, when I make trainer list, irrelevant training data overweights the model and model would be so poor in terms of accuracy.

What algorithms do you suggest to me?

And how would be the training data in terms of density of the each class?

Comment: I assume you have a classification project to classify documents among 30 topics and you've gathered a collection of labeled documents, from which you extract keywords. From that process, you got a total of 1.2 million keywords. If that is correct, what you are looking for is called "Feature Selection".

Comment: Have you tried omitting rare words (as they are likely to be trash)?

Comment: @PascalSoucy pretty close actually, I dont have labelled documents, I only have 1.2 million keywords to classify among 30 topics. And big portion of the keywords are garbage.